# Easier way to create animation for pacman

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, pacman

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/26/) code for pacman animation, it work's, but I could not understand what's going on there.

So, I tried to create easier animation for the same effect, using following code:

```
function name2(){
  $('.pacman').addClass('left');
  function name(){
    $('.pacman').removeClass('left');
  }
  setTimeout(name,1000);
}
setInterval(name2,100);
```

It work's, but the result look's ugly. How can i create the same animation in easier way?

Comment: "look's ugly" is not really a programming problem. Sounds more like something a customer would say to a designer :P Can you please be more specific - exactly what problems are you facing? If you don't like the way this animation looks then don't use it. I'm not to sure what exactly you are asking here.

Comment: toggleClass() learn about it.

Comment: @epascarello - I think the OP is referring to the animation as ugly and not the code :)

Comment: I would suggest using css animations for this

Comment: Where is the class `leftBorder`?

Comment: sorry, fix it - its  .left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way in my opinion would be using css:

```
.pacman{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 49px solid yellow;
  animation: pacman .5s ease-in-out infinite;|
}
@keyframes pacman {
  0% {
    border-left: 49px solid transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-left: 49px solid yellow;
  }
  100% {
    border-left: 49px solid transparent;
  }
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/f7RNQ/29/)